# PayPal preapproval request failed. User is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: php

I am using the paypal gateway. I have the error PayPal preapproval request failed. User is not allowed to perform this action.How can I solve this

Comment: What are you trying to do with the PayPal gateway when you get this error?

Comment: i am trying to do paypal subscription adaptive recurring payment i entered the app id username password and signature

Answer (score 0):

for adaptive payments you should have an App submitted and approved for that particular operation you are performing. If you already have one approved could be helpful to see the API call you are sending.

Andrea